# Android not changing my TextView when I need it to

Tags: android, eclipse

I need the text view to change and then the application should start the other processes, but what happens is, it does the work then goes and changes the text last.

I would appreciate any advice!

```
    public void onClick(View view) { 
    setText();
    work();
    }
```

I have tried

- Putting the set text code in the "work" code.
- Doing an if statement to check if the text view is updated before continuing

More Info

- Inside the "work" there is code for getting current location and sending it in an email.
- When the user presses the button I need text to change before the gps and email work starts.

Commplete code

```
public class VehicleInspection extends Activity {

    private RadioGroup radioQ1Group;
    private RadioButton radioQ1Button;
    private Button btnDisplay;
    EditText registration;
    EditText odometer;
    EditText comment;
    CheckBox Check1;
    CheckBox Check2;
    CheckBox Check3;
    CheckBox Check4;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    int go = 0;

    // GPSTracker Variables

        GPSTracker gps;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) { 
        super.onCreate(icicle); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_vehicle); 

        registration = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editRegistration);
        odometer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editOdometer);
        comment = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editComment);

        SharedPreferences sharedPref= getSharedPreferences("mypref", 0);
        String savedReg = sharedPref.getString("name", "");
        registration.setText(savedReg);

        Check1 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);    
        Check2 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);    
        Check3 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);    
        Check4 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);    

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 

        Button addImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSendVehicle); 
        addImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 

     public void onClick(View view) { 
                    setText();
                    if (go==1)
                    {
                    work();
                    }
                                    } 
    });
    }

        public void setText()
        {
            TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textComment);
            tv.setText("IT WORKED!");
            go = 1;
        }

        public void work()
        {  


             AccountManager manager = (AccountManager) getSystemService(ACCOUNT_SERVICE);
             Account[] list = manager.getAccounts();
             String gmail = null;
             String rating = null;
             String scheck1 = "FAIL";
             String scheck2 = "FAIL";
             String scheck3 = "FAIL";
             String scheck4 = "FAIL";
             Float ratingf = null;

             if(Check1.isChecked())
                 scheck1 = "PASS";
             if(Check2.isChecked())
                 scheck2 = "PASS";
             if(Check3.isChecked())
                 scheck3 = "PASS";
             if(Check4.isChecked())
                 scheck4 = "PASS";

             for(Account account: list)
             {
                 if(account.type.equalsIgnoreCase("com.google"))
                 {
                     gmail = account.name;
                     break;
                 }
             }

             gps = new GPSTracker(VehicleInspection.this);
             Mail m = new Mail("EMAIL@EMAIL", "); 

             String[] toArr = {"EMAIL@EMAIL"};      

             String message = ("From : " + gmail + "\n" + "Registration : " + registration.getText().toString() + "\n" + "Odometer : " + odometer.getText().toString() + "\nComment : " + comment.getText().toString()); 
             message = message + "\nTires : " + scheck1 + "\nExterior : " + scheck2 + "\nWindows : " + scheck3 + "\nInterior : " + scheck4;
             m.setFrom("EMAIL@EMAIL"); 
             m.setSubject("Yellolog : VI -" + " " + registration.getText().toString()); 
             m.setTo(toArr); 

             if(gps.canGetLocation()){

                 latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                 longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                 message = message + "\nLocation : \nLat : " + latitude + "\nLong : " + longitude;
                 m.setBody(message);

             }else{
            // can't get location
            // GPS or Network is not enabled
            // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
            gps.showSettingsAlert();
        }
      try { 
          //  m.addAttachment("/sdcard/filelocation"); 

            if(m.send()|| latitude != 0.0) { 
              Toast.makeText(VehicleInspection.this, "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

              // Create object of SharedPreferences.
              SharedPreferences sharedPref= getSharedPreferences("mypref", 0);
             //now get Editor
              SharedPreferences.Editor editor= sharedPref.edit();
             //put your value
              editor.putString("name", registration.getText().toString());       
            //commits your edits
              editor.commit();

              odometer.setText("");
              comment.setText("");
              Check1.setChecked(false);
              Check2.setChecked(false);
              Check3.setChecked(false);
              Check4.setChecked(false);
              TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textComment);
              tv.setText("Comment");


            } else { 
              Toast.makeText(VehicleInspection.this, "Email was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            } 
          } catch(Exception e) { 
            Toast.makeText(VehicleInspection.this, "There was a problem sending the email." + e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email",e ); 
          } 
        }
    }
```

Progress!!

```
    public void onClick(View view) { 

               tv.setText("IT WORKED!");

                if(tv.getText().toString().equals("IT WORKED!")){           
                runThread();  
              }else{
                 Toast.makeText(VehicleInspection.this, "Text Didnt change yet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

              }
                                } 
 });        
    }
    private void runThread() {

        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                while (i++ < 1000) {
                    try {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                work();

                            }
                        });
                        Thread.sleep(300);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

This makes the text change first, and the email gets sent, but the work() method doesn't end after email sends.

Comment: Did you rebuild before testing the changes you did from the "I have tried" section?

Comment: Post your complete code!

Comment: Yeah I did, it just goes and completes all the code in work and then goes to set the text. I nee the text to be set first

Comment: can you see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try out like this way:-

```
        addImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 

             public void onClick(View view) { 

                           TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textComment);
                    tv.setText("IT WORKED!");

        if(tv.getText().toString().equals("IT WORKED!")){
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                                      work();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });thread.start();

        }else{
    //paste code for error
    }
                                            } 
            });
```

Comment: Thank you! Ill try it immediately!

Comment: It still just goes and executes the code in work. Maybe the textview text is changed but it doesn't update the display on the screen or something...

Comment: try initialising the textView in onCreate and then try it out!!

Comment: Nope. It still sends the email then the text on screen changes to "it worked" any other ideas?

Comment: delay the time before work() method is called.Increase time if required

Comment: Progress!!! Thank you! I put work() in the runThread() and the text changes, then the email sends but work() takes forever to end.

Comment: That's great. if you think my answer worked for you then please do accept it..will help others too..!

Comment: remove this condition while (i++ < 1000) and use Thread.sleep(1000) before runOnUiThread

Comment: I will! As soon as its working good. Thank you so much for helping me

Answer (score 0):

can you try this:

```
public class my_asyntask  extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textComment); 
        protected void onPreExecute() {
         //you can set first here your textview 
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
         //do work in background
            return null; 
        }  


        protected void onPostExecute(String string) { 
        //finally settext your textview
        }  

    }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! It still does the same. I feel like the code is working but something is preventing the display from showing the changes till after the whole onclick is finished.

Comment: hi! I tried but no luck. When I click the view it freezes, completes all the code and then the app unfreezes and the change is made to the textView

Answer (score 0):

Try calling invalidate() method inside setText() method.

Comment: hi! I tried but no luck. When I click the view it freezes, completes all the code and then the app unfreezes and the change is made to the textView.

Answer (score 0):

try removing this condition `while (i++ < 1000)` and use `Thread.sleep(1000)` before runOnUiThread. Try like this:-

```
private void runThread() {


        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                 try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                          work();

                        }
                    });
                }

        }.start();
    }
```